# Get dynamically given div id's from document

Tags: php, javascript

I'm not a developer but I've been dabbling around with this for a while. Hope you can help

I have several div's with ID:s that are given to them dynamically through php. I have a function that is called through a checkbox which hides and shows the divs. What I want to do now is to get the div ids from the document and put them into the function.

I've kind of copied codes from different forums and it works if I'm hard coding the div names. Not sure what I'm doing now though, any help would be appreciated.

Here's what I have

Assigns id's to the divs:

```
$a .= "<div id='$go[media_caption]" . $i . "'>";
```

The function:

```
var editorial = [id^='editorial']);

function visiblox(arrDiv, hs) {
var disp = (hs) ? 'none' : 'block';
for(var x = 0; x < arrDiv.length; x++) {
document.getElementById(arrDiv[x]).style.display = disp;
    }

}

function chk(what, item) {
if(item) {
    visiblox(what, false);
} else {
    visiblox(what, true);
}
}
```

Calls the function:

```
<input type='checkbox' onclick='chk(editorial, this.checked);' checked> Editorial</p>
```

Comment: Is the issue that all your divs are being assigned the same ID?

Comment: The line `var editorial = [id^='editorial']);` is full of syntax errors. What do you what the `editorial` variable to contain?

Comment: I can imagine it is. Basically I want it to contain all the divs that start with 'editorial'. I want all of them to hide/show when I click the checkbox. Thanks

Comment: Rather, I want it to contain all the div IDs that start with editorial.. as a list separated by commas and a space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you have your PHP output an array for your Javascript to use? As PHP outputs the IDs, it would also add them to a string that is in the syntax of a Javascript array. Something like this:

```
$a .= "<div id='$go[media_caption]" . $i . "'>";
$jsIDs .= "'$go[media_caption]',";
```

Then at the end of the file, just before you the PHP file closes the `</body>` and `</html>` tags, output the array as a script:

```
$jsIDs = substr($jsIDs, 0, strlen($jdIDs)-1);  // strip off the last comma
$jsIDs = "<script type='text/javascript'>var idArr = [" . $jsIDs . "];</script>";
echo($jsIDs);
```

Then inside the javascript, you don't need to look up the IDs in the DOM. You can just use the array (in my example, I called it `idArr`).

---

UPDATE: Martin says the IDs output by PHP sometimes start with "editorial", some start with something else. To collect only the ones that start with "editorial", change the line above that starts with `$jsIDs .=` to these two lines:

```
if ( substr($go[media_caption], 9) == "editorial" )
    $jsIDs .= "'$go[media_caption]',";
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: I'm trying to get my head around this. The divs are created and assigned with IDs within a foreach ($pages as $go) in the php. So each DIV gets the name from an entry in the database, plus a number (the &i). Does this look right? foreach ($pages as $go) { 

  $a .= "<div id='$go[media_caption]" . $i . "'>";
  $jsIDs .= "'$go[media_caption]', ";

  }

Comment: When they are created, can they also be added to a list that will then be called in the javascript?

Comment: The basic idea is, in addition to generating HTML with PHP, you also generate a small amount of Javascript. Specifically, you use PHP to build a string containing a Javascript array. The Javascript array you build contains the IDs of the DIVs generated by the PHP.

Comment: So after the PHP line that appends to `$a`, also append to `$jsIDs`.  You want the `$jsIDs` string to look like this: `'id1','id2','id3',` etc. Finally, at the end, you strip off the trailing comma, and put valid Javascript code around the string, so it ends up looking like this:  `<script type='text/javascript'>var idArr=['id1','id2','id3'];</script>`.  That is a valid Javascript string, built by PHP and stored in a PHP string. You can output that with a PHP `echo` statement to include it as part of the HTML document PHP is building.

Comment: I think I figured it out! Thanks. No there's just one thing that I forgot to mention; There are different sets of divs. Some are called editorial, some are called something else. I'll have one corresponding checkbox for each. Is there a way to separate them from eachother; ie the $jsIDs will only contain strings that start with editorial?